# python import module fails

Tags: python, import, maya

```
custom/
    scripts/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        utilFile1.py
        utilFile2.py
        utilFile3.py
```

I have the above file structure I'm struggling trying to figure out how to import modules in python. I have gone through stackoverflow posts that have the same question but I still couldn't figure out why I can't get it to work.

I am trying to import these modules in maya and when I run 
`from utils import utilFile1` I get 
`ImportError: cannot import name utilFile1.`
Running `from custom.scripts.utils import utilFile1` gives me this error `ImportError: no module named custom.scripts.utils.` However if I run `import file1` it imports without any errors

I have appended custom/scripts to sys.path and when that didn't work, tried appending custom/scripts/utils as well, but that didn't work either. Based off some of the posts on stackoverflow, I saw some people suggesting to run "python -m" but I'm not sure if I should run this or where to execute it from.

I'm really at a loss as to why I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: Where are trying to import `utilFile1.py`?

Comment: From file1.py using from utils import utilFile1

Comment: Have you checked `utilFile1.py` for circular imports?

Comment: I'm not importing anything from file1 in utilFile1. file1 is importing from files in utils but it's failing on the 1st file I'm trying to import and none of them are importing anything from file1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have make it a python package by following steps,

in your root dir create setup.py,
in your case

```
custom/
    setup.py
       scripts/
       ...
       ...
```

in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='your_package_name',
    description='bla bla bla',
    version='0.0.1-dev',
    install_requires=[

    ],
)
```

and then hit

```
pip install -e .
```

---

for more info refer to [this docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)

Comment: can I run this on windows 10?

Comment: @dege yes you can

Answer (score 0):

Please update the directory structure as below.
Python might not be considering custom as a module as it doesn't have `__init__.py` file,

```
custom/
    __init__.py
    scripts/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        utilFile1.py
        utilFile2.py
        utilFile3.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Yash's method works, I believe that's what companies use to setup their environments. An alternative way is to add your scripts path as a PYTHONPATH in your maya.env file instead of using sys.path.append. I'm not sure why there's a difference or if it's coz I'm trying this on windows, but oddly enough it worked in my case.